# SQL find the day in October with highest sales from stores with promotion

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, left-join

I'm a SQL beginner here, really struggling with a challenge like this:

There are online events running all yearlong, I want to know:

1. On each day in October, how many stores participated in total, how many orders generated in total and how much sales generated in total.
2. What's the date with biggest sales volume from stores participated at events, what's the sales volume, and also what's the total sales volume from all stores (participated or not).

The DMBS I'm using is Postgres. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here are tables I have:

**table 1 - ele_slr_wide (all store ids)**

```
shop_id  
A000001
A000002
A000003
```

**table 2 - ele_slr_ord_wide_di (all orders)**

```
shop_id  order_id activity_id   pay_time   pay_amt
A000001  001       001         2019-10-25  100
A000001  002       002         2019-10-25  200
A000002  003       002         2019-10-27  200
A000003  004       NA          2019-10-25  100
```

**table 3 - ele_slr_act_wide (participating stores)**

```
shop_id  activity_id   start_time  end_time
A000001  001           2019-9-25   2019-10-31
A000001  002           2019-10-5   2019-10-31
A000002  002           2019-10-5   2019-10-31
```

**table 4 - ele_slr_ord_wide_di (participating stores orders)**

```
shop_id  order_id activity_id   pay_time   pay_amt
A000001  001       001         2019-10-25  100
A000001  002       001         2019-10-25  200
A000002  003       002         2019-10-27  200
```

Expected output 1:

```
Date      Participated_stores_count  total_orders   total_sales
2019-10-1           xxx                 xxx             xxx
...
2019-10-31          xxx                 xxx             xxx
```

Expected output 2:

```
Date_max_sales   sales_participated_stores   total_sales
2019-10-15           300                      400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below

**[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c7687ae7bcf0093656a349715d7940ef)**

**Query 1:**

```
WITH numbers as
(
    SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
    FROM generate_series( '2019-10-01'::timestamp , '2019-10-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) dd
)
SELECT date_trunc,COUNT(DISTINCT E.shop_id) ParticipatedStores, COUNT(DISTINCT ES.order_id) TotalOrders, SUM(ES.pay_amt) total_sales
FROM numbers n LEFT JOIN ele_slr_act_wide E ON   date_trunc BETWEEN E.start_time AND E.end_time
LEFT JOIN ele_slr_ord_wide_di ES ON E.shop_id = ES.shop_id AND  date_trunc = ES.pay_time
GROUP BY  date_trunc;
```

**Query 2:**

```
WITH numbers as
(
    SELECT date_trunc('day', dd):: date
    FROM generate_series( '2019-10-01'::timestamp , '2019-10-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) dd
)
SELECT date_trunc,COUNT(DISTINCT E.shop_id) ParticipatedStores, COUNT(DISTINCT ES.order_id) TotalOrders, SUM(ES.pay_amt) total_sales
FROM numbers n LEFT JOIN ele_slr_act_wide E ON   date_trunc BETWEEN E.start_time AND E.end_time
LEFT JOIN ele_slr_ord_wide_di ES ON E.shop_id = ES.shop_id AND  date_trunc = ES.pay_time
GROUP BY  date_trunc
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUM(ES.pay_amt) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(ES.pay_amt) END DESC
limit 1;
```

Output Will be

[image]